# Using express.js to render html, but html is not able to fetch JS files

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

I am using express.js to an HTML file which further calls a bunch of JS files. The server seems to be working, however the JS and CSS files configured within the HTML are not being fetched by the browser.

```
var express = require('C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/express')
var app = express()
var path = require('C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/path/path')

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/lib'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/img'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

My html file is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="./css/source-sans-pro.js"></script>
    <link href="css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<script id="home-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <header class="bar-title"><h1 class="title">Employee Directory</h1>    </header>
    <div class="bar-standard bar-header-secondary"><input class='search-key' type="text" style="height:31px;"/></div>
<div class="content"><ul class='list'></ul></div>
</script>

<script id="employee-li-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#.}}
    <li>
        <a href="#employees/{{this.id}}" class="tappable">
        <img src='img/{{firstName}}_{{lastName}}.jpg'/>
        <p>{{this.firstName}} {{this.lastName}}</p>
        <p>{{this.title}}</p>
        <span class="chevron"></span><span class="count">{{reports}}    </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    {{/.}}
</script>

<script id="employee-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <header class="bar-title"><a class="button-prev" href="#">Back</a><h1     class="title">Details</h1></header>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class="details">
            <img src='img/{{firstName}}_{{lastName}}.jpg'/>
            <h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>
            <h2>{{title}}</h2>
            <h2>{{city}}</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list inset" style="clear:both;">
            {{#if managerId}}
            <li><a href="#employees/{{managerId}}" class="tappable">    <p>View Manager</p><p>{{managerName}}</p><div class="action-icon     icon-manager"/></a></li>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if reports}}
            <li><a href="#employees/{{id}}/reports" class="tappable">    <p>View Direct Reports</p><p>{{reports}}</p><div class="action-icon     icon-reports"/></a></li>
            {{/if}}
            <li><a href= "spark_widget.html?email={{email}}"     target="_blank"><img src="/pix/byron_bay_225x169.jpg" ></a></li>
            <li><a href="spark_widget.html?email={{email}}&call=1"     target="_blank"><img src="/pix/byron_bay_225x169.jpg" </a></li>
            <li><a href="message:{{cellPhone}}" class="tappable">    <p>Message</p><p>{{cellPhone}}</p><div class="action-icon icon-sms"/>    </a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:{{email}}" class="tappable"><p>Email</p>    <p>{{email}}</p><div class="action-icon icon-mail"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="sms:{{cellPhone}}" class="tappable"><p>Map</p>    <p>{{city}}</p><div class="action-icon icon-location"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="reports-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <header class="bar-title"><a class="button-prev" href="#">Back</a><h1     class="title">Direct Reports</h1></header>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class="details">
            <img src='img/{{firstName}}_{{lastName}}.jpg'/>
            <h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>
            <h2>{{title}}</h2>
            <h2>{{city}}</h2>
        </div>
         <ul class="list"></ul>
    </div>
</script>

<script src="./phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/zepto.min.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="./js/storage/memory-store.js"></script>
<script src="./js/HomeView.js"></script>
<script src="./js/EmployeeView.js"></script>
<script src="./js/ReportsView.js"></script>
<script src="./js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I render this using an IIS server, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: The browser renders a blank screen. However when you view source, you can see the index.html. But its not fetching anything else.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to specify paths for node modules,
just do this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd discourage you from using absolute paths when using node. I'd suggest configuring your Windows environment, so it works correctly with npm, then package.json should tell the npm what modules are required.

When you finish with your configuration your first line should look like this:

`var express = require('express');`

Additionally, consider moving on to es6 and use const/let instead of var. But that's another topic.

Your problem is that resources files are unknown for the browser.

For express, it's better to run it locally and use it in a browser navigating to localhost: PORT.

Then, resources could be requested from relative urls like "/css/foo.css".

Then, when your website is deployed it won't get lost when the hostname changes.

Comment: As an additional note. Always check the devtools networking tab in this kind of problems. It will probably give you some hints and make you understand what browser actually does.

Comment: I did check the devtools and saw that the dependent files were not being called by the browser. Its not even trying to send an HTTP request to the express server, just rendering the index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're script 'src' is correct in your html page.  If your css is in you styles folder you'd have to source it like so
 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">`
Also make sure that the order of your files are correct.  You will want to source your js first.  If all else fails try using the jq or js cdn.  Google Jquery CDN or whatever language you're using and copy and paste the cdn in your `<head>`.  I wouldn't recommend doing it regularly.  CDN's don't work without internet.